# Is it legal to mail a non-explosive "glitter bomb" to myself to dissuade a mail carrier from tampering with my packages?

Tags: united-states, mail, ohio

Every single package my mail main delivers is ripped open. Once, I ordered stamps on line. The mailer was ripped open & the stamps gone. Paperwork still there though. He claimed it got ripped in the sorter. I *used* to collect coins & buy them off Ebay, but they mysteriously disappeared during delivery. Apparently that includes boxes too, now. He just smiles as he looks me in the eye as he hands me yet another ripped up package/box/mailer, so this is not a "porch pirate" offense.

I want to mail a glitter bomb to myself repeatedly to dissuade him from ripping open my packages. I was thinking a spring loaded false bottom sort of set up. No explosives whatsoever. Just a bunch of glitter, cardboard & spring.

This is occurring in Ohio in the United States of America.

Comment: In case you are wondering, I forgot to include he actually hands these packages directly to me and looks me in the eye doing so. There is no porch pirate included in this particular scenario.

Comment: Do you have a legal question here?

Comment: If in the US, go talk to the postmaster.

Answer (score 4):

You did not mention the country where you are, but this sounds like a **very** bad idea. Any working "glitter bomb" will be a low-grade bomb and setting one of those is extremely illegal.

If you know when the next parcel will arrive, my advice would be to arrange for a credlible witness and to take pictures of the parcel before you open it any further. Then report the damage to the sender. If it was a commercial parcel, ask for a full refund. Enough of that and the postal inspectors will wonder why their machines are "damaging" so much mail.

Comment: You may not know what a so-called "glitter bomb" is. It's not a bomb of any kind, it is just an envelope with glitter. It's not something that you "set", and it is not illegal, it's just childish.

Comment: To add to this, OP intends for the glitter bomb to "detonate" inside a postal vehicle or office. This would likely damage a lot of unrelated mail and open OP up to a range of torts, both civil and criminal.